# Showing $\dim T_0 ℝ^n = n$ using a derivation definition for the tangent space.

Tags: differential-geometry

I’m trying to (re-)prove that $\dim_ℝ \mathrm{Der}_ℝ(C^1(ℝ^n)) = n$, where $$\mathrm{Der}_ℝ(C^1(ℝ^n)) = \{δ\colon C^1(ℝ^n) → ℝ;~\text{$δ$ is a $ℝ$-linear derivation}\},$$
and the $C^1(ℝ^n)$-module-structure on $ℝ$ is given by $f·x = f(0)·x$.

In order to this I only need to show that for a derivation $δ ∈ \mathrm{Der}_ℝ(C^1(ℝ^n))$, if evaluated at the projections $x_1, …, x_n \colon ℝ^n → ℝ$, $δ(x_1) = 0, …, δ(x_n) = 0$, then $δ = 0$.

In other words: For $f ∈ C^1(ℝ^n)$, I need to relate $δ(f)$ to $δ(x_1), …, δ(x_n)$ in some way. But I’m stuck! I guess I need to invest that derivations vanish on constant functions.

I would gladly see a little *hint*.

---

*Update*: I would love to use Stone–Weierstraß on the algebra generated by $x_1, …, x_n$ (on which any derivation with $δ(x_1) = 0, …, δ(x_n) = 0$ must vanish). But as $δ$ is rather discontinuous, this doesn’t help much, does it?

Comment: Do you know that the basis is $\{ \partial_{x_i} \}$, right? Then you have to use Taylor series and a little of calculus (analysis).

Comment: @user40276 I know that $∂_{x_i};~i=1,…,n$ is the basis (but that’s what I’m trying to prove of course). Is there a way to avoid Taylor series/is there a more structural approach?

Comment: Sorry, but you have to use analysis somewhere, unless you want the proof in the algebro-geometric setting (which is a different setting). I think you can find the proof in almost any introductory book to manifolds. Warner's book is one example.

Comment: @user40276 Since I’m working on $C^1$ functions, Taylor only gives me $f(x) = f(0) + f'[ξ_x]·x$, but I can’t use $δ$ on the expression $∂f/∂_{x_i}(ξ_x)$ because $∂f/∂_{x_i}(ξ_x)$ as a function of $x$ isn’t $C^1$ – do I maybe need to work with $C^∞$ functions?

Comment: Oh! You're working with $C^1$. In this case, I don't know if the proof that I was mentioning holds. But I think the statement still true. I think there must be  a proof in some introductory book on manifolds. See John Lee's book and Jeffrey Lee's book, maybe you will find something...

Comment: Ok, for the proof I have mentioned you need at least $C^2$. For the $C^1$ case I don't know.

Comment: Found out: If one only considers *continuous* derivations, it follows from Stone–Weierstraß without any further analysis.